# Java + rock paper scissors game + OOP(?)

Tags: java, oop

I have an assignment to make a rock paper scissors game that will allow the user to input "R, P, S, or Q to quit." If user enters Q to quit, it must display the wins and losses and in percentage format. I tried dabbling with inheritance, but I made this in case I don't find a more efficient, probably more OOP way to go about this.

**My question is:** Is there a quicker, more efficient way to code this? OOP seems like it could work, but it doesn't have to be.

```
// main method
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    // variables
    double wins = 0;
    double losses = 0;
    double draws = 0;
    double games = 0;
    Integer answer1 = null;

    boolean playing = true;

    // start of game
    while (playing) 
    {
        // main menu
        System.out.println("Input R, P, S, or Q(to quit).");
        String answer = scan.next();

        // player's move
        answer = answer.toLowerCase();

        // computer's move
        Random random = new Random();
        Integer choice = random.nextInt(3); // n-1
        String comp = choice.toString();
        System.out.println(comp);

        // converts player's move from str to int
        switch (answer)
        {
        case "r":
            answer1 = 0;
            break;
        case "p":
            answer1 = 1;
            break;
        case "s":
            answer1 = 2;
            break;
        case "q":
            System.out.println("User exit.");
            double winP = wins/games*100;
            double loseP = losses/games*100;
            double drawP = draws/games*100;

            System.out.println("Wins: " + wins);
            System.out.printf("%.2f", winP);
            System.out.println(" Percent");
            System.out.println("Losses: " + losses);
            System.out.printf("%.2f", loseP);
            System.out.println(" Percent");
            System.out.println("Draws: " + draws);
            System.out.printf("%.2f", drawP);
            System.out.println(" Percent");
            answer1 = null;
            playing = false;
            break;
        }

        // checks for conditions
        // draw
        if (playing == true) 
        {
            if (answer1 == choice)
            {
                System.out.println("Draw");
                draws++;
                games++;
            }
            // losses
            if (answer1 == 0 && choice == 1)
            {
                System.out.println("YOU LOSE! :D");
                losses++;
                games++;
            }
            if (answer1 == 1 && choice == 2)
            {
                System.out.println("YOU LOSE! :D");
                losses++;
                games++;
            }
            if (answer1 == 2 && choice == 0)
            {
                System.out.println("YOU LOSE! :D");
                losses++;
                games++;
            }
            // wins
            if (answer1 == 0 && choice == 2)
            {
                System.out.println("you win... :D");
                wins++;
                games++;
            }
            if (answer1 == 1 && choice == 0)
            {
                System.out.println("you win... :D");
                wins++;
                games++;
            }
            if (answer1 == 2 && choice == 1)
            {
                System.out.println("you win... :D");
                wins++;
                games++;
            }
        }           
    }
}
```

Comment: a first cut for you might be to try to factor out the actions in the game as methods. If something is too complex, try to decompose it into smaller chunks.

Comment: Sure. What abstractions into objects did you come up with?

Comment: all those if statements under `if(playing == true)` could be turned into a nested switch statement

Comment: You should have a default case, also you should use logic-gates to determine if you win or lose, in order to reduce all the else-if logic.

Comment: "quicker, more efficient" - in what regard?  All things considered, that looks like a pretty small chunk of code, outside of a few sort of nitpicky things, such as what @3kings mentioned.

Comment: you can simplify most your conditions by `(answer1 + 1) % 3 == choice` and `(choice +1) % 3 == answer`

Comment: all the stuff in `case q` could go outside the loop.

Comment: @njzk2 Or switch on the value of `(answer1 - choice + 3) % 3`

Comment: and your whole question could go to code review http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: You should check out other solutions on Code Review to Rock Paper Scissors Lizard Spock, here is my solution for example. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/73369/rock-paper-scissors-lizard-spock-game

Comment: Another possibility is the use `enum { ROCK, PAPER, SCISSORS }`. Then you could do `option.ordinal()` to get the values `0`, `1`, `2`. Using `ordinal` should be rare, but I think it's appropriate here.

Comment: @njzk2 you are right. I will move this to the codereview section. I did not know it was a thing, but thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version of rock, paper, scissors that I did.  I have a GameModel class that holds the values for a rock, paper, scissors game, and a RockPaperScissors class that provides the user interface.

Here's an example of the user interface:

```
Rock, Paper, Scissors; Enter r, p, s, or q to quit: s
We chose the same item.  Let's try again.

Rock, Paper, Scissors; Enter r, p, s, or q to quit: s
You chose Scissors, the computer chose Rock.  The computer wins.

Rock, Paper, Scissors; Enter r, p, s, or q to quit: r
You chose Rock, the computer chose Paper.  The computer wins.

Rock, Paper, Scissors; Enter r, p, s, or q to quit: s
We chose the same item.  Let's try again.

Rock, Paper, Scissors; Enter r, p, s, or q to quit: s
You chose Scissors, the computer chose Rock.  The computer wins.

Rock, Paper, Scissors; Enter r, p, s, or q to quit: q

The final score: Player 0, Computer 3, ties 2.
```

And here's the code:

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RockPaperScissors implements Runnable {

    private GameModel gameModel;

    private Random random;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new RockPaperScissors().run();
    }

    public RockPaperScissors() {
        this.random = new Random();
        this.gameModel = new GameModel();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        char inputChar = getUserChoice(scanner);
        while (inputChar != gameModel.getQuitCharacter()) {
            char computerChar = generateComputerChoice();
            System.out.println(gameModel.calculateGameResult(inputChar,
                    computerChar));
            inputChar = getUserChoice(scanner);
        }

        System.out.println(gameModel.displayFinalScore());

        scanner.close();
    }

    private char getUserChoice(Scanner scanner) {
        char inputChar = ' ';

        while (gameModel.getCharacterIndex(inputChar) < 0) {
            System.out.print(gameModel.generatePrompt());
            String input = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase();
            inputChar = input.charAt(0);
        }

        return inputChar;
    }

    private char generateComputerChoice() {
        int index = random.nextInt(gameModel.getChoicesLength() - 1);
        return gameModel.getChoiceCharacter(index);
    }

    public class GameModel {

        private final String[] CHOICES = { "Rock", "Paper", "Scissors", "Quit" };

        private int playerScore;
        private int computerScore;
        private int tieScore;

        public GameModel() {
            this.playerScore = 0;
            this.computerScore = 0;
            this.tieScore = 0;
        }

        public String getChoice(int index) {
            return CHOICES[index];
        }

        public char getChoiceCharacter(int index) {
            return CHOICES[index].toLowerCase().charAt(0);
        }

        public int getChoicesLength() {
            return CHOICES.length;
        }

        public char getQuitCharacter() {
            return getChoiceCharacter(getChoicesLength() - 1);
        }

        public int getPlayerScore() {
            return playerScore;
        }

        public int getComputerScore() {
            return computerScore;
        }

        public int getTieScore() {
            return tieScore;
        }

        public String generatePrompt() {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            builder.append(CHOICES[0]);
            builder.append(", ");
            builder.append(CHOICES[1]);
            builder.append(", ");
            builder.append(CHOICES[2]);
            builder.append("; Enter ");
            builder.append(getChoiceCharacter(0));
            builder.append(", ");
            builder.append(getChoiceCharacter(1));
            builder.append(", ");
            builder.append(getChoiceCharacter(2));
            builder.append(", or ");
            builder.append(getChoiceCharacter(3));
            builder.append(" to ");
            builder.append(CHOICES[3].toLowerCase());
            builder.append(": ");

            return builder.toString();
        }

        public String calculateGameResult(char inputChar, char computerChar) {
            if (inputChar == computerChar) {
                tieScore++;
                return "We chose the same item.  Let's try again.\n";
            } else {
                int inputIndex = getCharacterIndex(inputChar);
                int computerIndex = getCharacterIndex(computerChar);
                String s = "You chose " + CHOICES[inputIndex]
                        + ", the computer chose " + CHOICES[computerIndex]
                        + ".  ";

                int testIndex = (inputIndex + 1) % (CHOICES.length - 1);
                if (testIndex == computerIndex) {
                    computerScore++;
                    return s + "The computer wins.\n";
                } else {
                    playerScore++;
                    return s + "You win.\n";
                }
            }
        }

        private int getCharacterIndex(char c) {
            for (int index = 0; index < CHOICES.length; index++) {
                if (c == getChoiceCharacter(index)) {
                    return index;
                }
            }

            return -1;
        }

        public String displayFinalScore() {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            builder.append("\nThe final score: Player ");
            builder.append(playerScore);
            builder.append(", Computer ");
            builder.append(computerScore);
            builder.append(", ties ");
            builder.append(tieScore);
            builder.append(".");

            return builder.toString();
        }

    }

}
```